# What is considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, allowed-topics

What is one domain or example question that you consider to be off topic? (Please post just one per answer.)

[Return to FAQ index](/q/362)

Comment: You guys had some reasonable on- and off-topic questions defined in [the definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2578?phase=definition) for this site - taking some of the arguments made there (even if those arguments are nothing more than, "I'm basically voting down every question that I can only imagine being asked by a man with a bong in his hand"), fleshing them out and applying them to questions being asked now would be a good start...

Comment: I think that the phrase "I can only imagine this being asked by a man with a bong in his hand" *definitely* needs to go in the FAQ or the close reason text somewhere...

Answer (score 6):

- Questions about teaching philosophy should probably be on topic; those about job prospects for majors should probably be off topic.

Comment: there are job prospects for philosophy majors?

Comment: @ajray: You could teach? Or do basically anything. You have a degree in liberal arts. It's really no more or less useful than, say, a degree in history. But that should definitely be off-topic here.

Comment: @ajray: Rants about the absence of job prospects should be off-topic, too.

Answer (score 6):

[Legal questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/284/73) should be off-topic.

(There is, I suppose, a philosophy of law, but it would probably start at a much higher level than copyright.)

Comment: The link doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

- questions about the meaning of life are off-topic
- zen koans are off topic (anything starting with "if a tree...")

Comment: What is the sound of one hand closing a zen thread?

Comment: *Ka-Ban!* Yes? I'd say that Zen koans are on topic *if* they are questioning elements of zen philosophy. Smart-ass questions, however, are right out.

Comment: I think koans are on-topic, but their answers are off-topic.

Comment: Questions about the meaning of life are off topic?!  Are you kidding?  That's what philosophy's all about!!

Answer (score 4):

Any question that would not even be considered for a undergraduate exam should be off-topic here.
For example, those questions that:

- display no domain awareness whatsoever (have you done *any* research? ANY?)
- are too broad (which is almost certainly a consequence of not understanding the domain)
- require, due to their scope, more than a thousand words to answer

Comment: While I agree those sorts of questions are off-topic, I'd also encourage all of us to consider using comments (or in some cases answers) to correct the askers.  Lack of domain awareness will be common, but sometimes a small nudge toward getting the asker to do research could very well convert a bad question into a better or even great question.

Comment: We don't need another MathOverflow

Comment: I like your restrictions, I don't like the reference to undergraduate exams. I don't think they match, and I dislike the exclusionary "you have to be an undergraduate" implications. (See discussions on Area51 on allowing only undergraduates to a site, etc). Get rid of that, and you'll get a +1. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that questions like [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/244/looking-for-a-quote-source) are off-topic, whereas actual questions related to logic and reasoning are on-topic.

Comment: Can you go into detail on *why* that question would be off-topic?

Comment: I can see how that question, reformulated, could be decent. It's just a bad question right now though... But yes, explain your reasoning, please.

Comment: Ehh, for a counter-example, look at [this question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/238/who-said-they-were-hiding-in-the-woods). It basically asks **exactly** the same thing: "who said x?" But it asks it in a much more coherent, well-thought-out way. **That's** what we want to encourage. There's no reason to ban this type of question in general, at least given that it's obviously something said by a philosopher.... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Beginner cogito style questions are **off topic**, e.g.:

1 How do I know I'm not a brain in a jar
2 How can I be sure I'm not dreaming?
3 Do I exist?

Comment: Erm, I can't tell if you're [for](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-is-off-topic/58#58) or [against](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-is-off-topic/59#59) this... You should take a position and post *that* as your answer.

Comment: @Cody you're right it's just two sides not a third "I don't care"

Comment: I believe that they are on topic.

Comment: I think those questions should be on-topic, but the *many* duplicates we are likely to see in September should be redirected to a canonical set of questions.  I.e, we should only answer them *once*.

Comment: They may be on-topic, but they are obviously poorly formed and fall into requiring 1000+ words to answer.

Answer (score 2):

There should never be any more [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/7/73)s under either the `zombie` or the `apocalypse` tags.

Comment: Actually zombies are a really fascinating thought experiment for free will... But it does have to have philosophical content beyond "a man with a bong asked this"

Comment: @Brian is quite right here. Zombies are invoked in many thought experiments about not just free will, but also philosophy of mind.

Comment: I was considering allowing an exception or two for the `apocalypse` tag. ;-)  Can we at least agree to no more conjunctions of those two tags?