# Do high rep users on stackexchange have issues with philosophical questions that might relate to life?

Tags: discussion

Do high rep users on stackexchange have issues with philosophical questions that might relate to life? Do philosophers not ask those sorts of questions?

Can't people here just vote on the basis of what is, or at least seems to be, of philosophical interest?

Comment: [Possible reason 1](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/friends-we-are-not-philosophers), [possible reason 2](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3927/17209). Primarily, this is a StackExchange community, secondarily, this is about the subject matter philosophy. This does confine the kinds of questions that are a good fit here. Users usually do not have a problem with the specific topic of a question but with them being unspecific regarding what would make a good answer or soliciting opinions.

Comment: so it (those sorts of questions) is off topic only cos it would be answered off topic? i could get that @PhilipKlöcking

Comment: Essentially yes, if a good answer would take a book (too broad/unspecified) or be based on opinion or one-sided, the question is off-topic not in the sense of "topic of philosophy" but "scope of this site".

Comment: ok i'll stop it, apologies @PhilipKlöcking and thanks. maybe one day my questions will be upvoted, be some kind of herald of the dawn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ethics is clearly an important part of philosophy, and the [ethics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) tag is even the second most used tag on this site. But there are lots of schools of ethics:

- deontological
- divine command
- hedonism
- natural rights based
- utilitarianism
- virtue
- etc.

These schools of ethics will sometimes give opposite answers to whether a course of action is ethical or not. For this reason general ethical questions (Is it good to do X?) will often be closed as primarily opinion based. This can be avoided by scoping the question to a particular school of ethics (How do utilitarians decide if it is good to do X?)

Comment: i downvoted because it doesn't really try to address the issue / question

Comment: @another_name Explain? You asked if SE has issues with philosophical questions relating to life, and ethics definitely fits that!

Comment: i just mean found most of it irrelevant to the question, other than noting that ethics is philosophy.

Comment: @another_name If Ethics matches what you're asking about then your question is based on a false assumption.

Comment: no false assumption, only an answer in the negative

Comment: So if I've answered your question why did you say I didn't really address your question?

Comment: oh because most of the answer was irrelevant to the question. it's not a bother, i'm just suggesting it would be better as a comment

Comment: i accepted the answer, tho you make it look like only the sub-discipline of ethics has relevance to life. that seems untrue?

Comment: @another_name I didn't mean that, just that ethics is one discipline which clearly does have relevance to life.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps philosophy.stackexchange is a (quite) wonderful demonstration that philosophy, art, life, is not an object in navel gazing, but about itself.

Comment: haha, more downovtes! yay!

Comment: The thing you do not seem to quite understand is something that many 20th century philosophers have stated time and again: There is no point in asking and answering questions on life itself since it is too complex and individual. Life is something that just has to be lived, which is both a prerogative and a responsibility. Also, Philosophy.SE is not philosophy. Most academic philosophy is not quite philosophical. Wrap your head about what you expect from others and where to get it, this is not a good place for counselling.

Comment: it's counseling is it @PhilipKlöcking ? they are questions about philosophy that have bearing on my life that only a philosopher can answer. if you call that "counseling" so be it, but seems like a misnomer. you don't even seem dismissive, more like someone who likes to browbeat about the superiority of their own psychology. that is unnecessary, and far poorer use of the site than how i use it

Comment: so what did you mean @PhilipKlöcking ?